# Differential function as a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the Linear Map $T\colon P_{3}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$
>   given by the 
>   set of infintely differentiable functions 
>   1) $T(f)\colon x \mapsto xf'(x)$ , Prove that $T$ is linear. 
>   2) What is $\ker T$ ?.

For 1) i think I make I have made this sort of error before, I think
of an input like

$ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+1$ so the derivative would be $3ax^{2}+2bx+c$
then then $T(x)$ would be $3ax^{3}+2bx^{2}+cx$ and similarly

$T(y) = 3ay^{3}+2by^{2}+cy$ but $T(x+y) = (x+y)f'(x+y) =(x+y)[f'(x)+f'(y)]
=xf'(x)+xf'(y) +yf'(x)+yf'(y)$ which is clearly 
not equal to $T(x)+T(y)$ and similarly $T(cx) = cxf'(cx) \neq cT(x)=
cxf'(x)$, where am i going wrong here ?

For 2) would the kernal be $x: \{0\} \cup c$ where $c$ is a constant
since $x =0$ will output zero, and the differentiation of any constant
is zero.

Comment: Don't you mean $(T(f))(x):=xf'(x)$?

Comment: yes that is what is mean

Comment: So this is the answer to your question. Instead of dealing with $x$ and $y$, deal with $ax^3+bx^2+\ldots$ and $a'x^3+b'x^2+\ldots$ and show that $T$ takes the sum to the sum of images.

Comment: This is in many ways the root of your problem; you need to check that $T(f)$ is linear in $f$, so if $f$ and $g$ are two differentiable functions, then $T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g)$ (and something similar for scalars). You shouldn't try to check linearity in the arguments of the functions $f$ and $g$, because it won't hold, as you point out. Said differently, you want to check that $T(f+g)(x)=T(f)(x)+T(g)(x)$, *not* that $T(f)(x+y)=T(f)(x)+T(f)(y)$ - this second statement says that $T(f)$ is linear, rather than that $T$ is linear, and this won't be true for general $f$.

Comment: For part 2), you've described the set slightly inefficiently, because $0$ is itself a constant, so it isn't a special case. You have proved that this set is contained in the kernel; why is it the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the notation should be $T(f)$ instead of the confusing $T(x)$, because the symbol $f$ would othewise remain undefined.

In any reasonable way, $T(f+g)=x(f(x)+g(x))'=xf'(x)+xg'(x)$ by the linearity of the derivative.

Assume that $xf'(x)=0$, the null polynomial of degree (at most) three. Then $xf'(x)$ is a polynomial of degree (at most) three without constant term. Its coefficients must vanish, and we remain with $f(x)=a_0$, a constant polynomial.
It is trivial now to conclude that $\ker T$ is exactly the set of constant polynomials.